# What does the argument --client=2 do in Dropbox?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

I have just installed and launched Dropbox. I see:

[image]

What does the argument --client=2 do?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Dropbox don't release details of how their software works, but it's almost certainly just a flag to change some internal configuration.

Either there are old and new versions of the client built into the exe (unlikely) or something like separate procedures to use when running on different versions of windows. Chances are --client=2 tells the application "use Windows XP libraries" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are seeing this because you have a Dropbox for Business account and a personal one linked to it. Therefore, you have two instances of Dropbox running on your computer. That argument means that process is the second instance of Dropbox running on your computer. The second instance of Dropbox (the one with the argument) is started by the first instance of Dropbox by passing that parameter.

Passing that argument yourself would not be advised as the two instances work together so without a main Dropbox instance running, it is useless. Also note that "2" is specific to your computer. It could be different on another computer or if you link/unlink your account several times.